# Are these confidence intervals already Bonferoni adjusted?

Tags: regression, bonferroni

I'm new to STATA and just have a simple question
I have the simple regression output seen below. I'm wondering if the 95% Ci of B1 and B0 is already bonferoni adjusted?

[image]

Comment: Statistical software really should not do that. 1) Bonferroni saps away your power (intervals are unnecessarily wide) when you have many comparisons, and Bonferroni-Holm is better, even if slightly harder to implement. 2) Perhaps not all confidence intervals are of interest, so for how many intervals do you adjust? // That said, I am not a STATA user.

Comment: You can answer your own question by writing an answer in the box below. Please do not vandalize your question. When you posted on SE, you gave up 
ownership of the content under
[CC BY-SA 4.0](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/licensing). If there are 
no answers, you may delete your own question (see 
[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)
): just click the faint gray 'delete' at lower left (your account needs to be 
registered for this). Otherwise, the thread will remain according to SE's rules.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the CIs nor the p-values from regression output are bonferroni adjusted, neither in Stata nor in any other software. If the regression coefficients actually comprise a prespecified set of hypotheses from you, the user, you will need to manually correct the p-values and confidence intervals.